# Como salvar todo o projeto usando Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

tudo bem?

Estou usando Visual Studio Code, e quando faço alteração em três arquivos, tenho que ir de arquivo para arquivo para salvar cada um individualmente.

Existe algum comando no **Visual Studio Code** para salvar todos o projeto de uma vez só?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe outra opção, que seria vc configurar o "**Auto Save**" do VS Code. Assim seus arquivos sempre vão estar salvos sem precisar de nenhum comando

Vá em <kbd>**File > Preferences > Settings**</kbd>  e depois pesquise por "auto save"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na opção `'onFocusChange'` por exemplo em qualquer lugar que vc clicar fora da janela ele vai salvar sozinho, inclusive trocando de uma aba para outra.

Se vc optar pela opção de "*afterDelay*" ele por default salva a cada 1000ms, mas vc pode configurar como no exemplo abaixo.

```
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"files.autoSaveDelay": 500,
```

> A vantagem desse método é que se vc fechar o programa ou acabar a luz ele vai salvar sozinho as informações

Link da documentação oficial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save

Answer (score 4):

Você pode habilitar o [***Auto save***](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save) no menu ***File***.

Também no menu ***File*** tem a opção de ***Save All***, que seria a combinação de atalho `Ctrl + K S`.

Mas para funcionar você tem que pressionar o `Ctrl + K`, soltar `Ctrl + K` e presionar o `S`.

A combinação `Ctrl + K Ctrl + S` é para abrir o *[Keyboard Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)*, sendo aqui que você pode customizar os atalhos do VSCode. Experimente alterar a opção *Save All* para algo que seja mais fácil de você utilizar.

Comment: não entendi, se eu digitar Ctrl + k + S aparece um atalho para todas as linhas de comando, se eu digitar Ctrl + k não acontece nada e se eu digitar Ctrl + S somente salva o arquivo correspondente.
Como devo digitar?

Comment: eu testei a sua sugestão e nós dois sabemos que isso não funcionar, você nem ao menos testou sua sugestão.

Comment: @wladyband funciona sim, você que não soube usar o comando.

Comment: @wladyband como o colega falou  [ctrl] + [k], solta e depois aperta o [S]